# use asprintf in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a kernel module, there I'm using procfs file with read permission,
when read from user-space, I need to create a formatted string locally, and copy to user.
the size of data data that should be written in the buffer is unknown - that why I want to use something like asprintf in the kernel. is there anything like that? or another idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The simplest option would be to use `proc_create_single_data` to create the file. One of the parameters is a pointer to a "show" function that produces the data when the file is read. The "show" function has a `struct seq_file *` and a context pointer passed by `proc_create_single_data`. You can use functions such as `seq_printf` to write formatted string data to the proc file.

Comment: is it more expensive? performance I mean..

Comment: It depends if you want to show more than 4095 bytes of data. If you write more than that to the proc file, it will keep doubling its buffer size, discard the old "show" output, and call your "show" function again until it fits. (However, once it's increased the buffer size, it will keep that buffer size until the proc file is closed.)

Comment: `asprintf` doesn't exist in the kernel. The nearest equivalent is `kasprintf`, which prints to a dynamically allocated buffer that you need to `kfree` afterwards. Efficiency wise, it always does the formatted output twice, first with a null buffer to determine the output length, and second with a dynamically allocated buffer of the correct length.

Comment: when using seq_printf - in which stage the data is copied to user?
and also, if i want to read more than 4096 bytes, should I prefer to implement my own read with biggest local buffer - and copy just when this buffer is full?

Comment: You don't get to choose when the data is copied to the user. If using `proc_create_single_data`, it will be shortly after your `show` handler function is called, which will be due to the user either reading of lseeking the proc file. The `show` handler should generate the whole contents of the file. If the contents you generate is too big, it will be discarded and your `show` handler will be called again with a larger buffer, but it should still generate the whole contents of the file each time it is called.

Comment: If you have more complicated needs, such as data consisting of a large number of independent data "records", the `proc_create_single_data` interface might not be the best to use, but you can still use the more complicated, general `seq_file` interface if you use `proc_create_seq_private`, `proc_create_seq_data` or `proc_create_seq` to create the file. See the [documentation for the `seq_file` interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt) for details. Or you can use the full-blown file operations if you use `proc_create_data` and really know what you are doing.